# "Module file was created by an older version of the compiler" message when trying to run UI Test on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to do some UI Testing on my older project.
I created a UI Test target and added `@testable import MyOlderProject` at the top of the test Swift file.

I'm getting the following error message:

> Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild
>   'MyOlderProject' and try again

Looks like it's related to MyOlderProject.swiftmodule/arm.swiftmodule.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upgrade to Xcode 7 GM and build your app with latest swift compiler?
It might be a warning sign from here,

> "To be safe, all components of your app should be built with the same
>   version of Xcode and the Swift compiler to ensure that they work
>   together."

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2